# Python "and if" equivalent

Tags: python, if-statement

assume "mylist" can contain the values "video", "audio", "visual" or all three. I want my script to append the matching data to the list "files" if the string is found in"mylist" this works if there is only one string in "mylist", but if there is more than one string, only the first string in "mylist" gets matched. Is there something I could use instead of "elif" that is equivalent to "and if"?

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    mylist = request.POST.getlist('list')
    files = []
    if 'video' in mylist:
      files.append('/home/dbs/public_html/download/codex/codex.html')
    elif 'audio' in mylist:
      files.append('/home/dbs/public_html/download/audio/audio_player.html')
    elif 'visual' in mylist:
      files.append('/home/dbs/public_html/download/visual/visual.html')
    return HttpResponse(files)
  else:
    return http.HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use `if` instead of `elif`.

```
if 'video' in mylist:
    files.append('/home/dbs/public_html/download/codex/codex.html')
if 'audio' in mylist:
    files.append('/home/dbs/public_html/download/audio/audio_player.html')
if 'visual' in mylist:
    files.append('/home/dbs/public_html/download/visual/visual.html')
```

You could also use a mapping object and a loop which would be nicer in case there were more than a few items since you don't have to repeat the `` `... in mylist `` code:

```
paths = {
    'video': '/home/dbs/public_html/download/codex/codex.html',
    'audio': '/home/dbs/public_html/download/audio/audio_player.html',
    'visual': '/home/dbs/public_html/download/visual/visual.html'
}

files += [path for key, path in paths.iteritems() if key in mylist]
```

Comment: @ngmiceli That's why he's the Thief Master   :)

Answer (score 5):

Why not just if? You want each case *if* it occurs. There is no relationship between each clause.
:)